# How to reorder nodes in Drupal 7 using Drag and Drop feature?

Tags: nodes

Can anyone please help me that, how I can reorder the nodes in Drupal 7 using drag and drop feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a view to list your nodes and use Drupal [draggable views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JE8R.png) module to order your nodes.

> From the documentation page,
>
> - Order any type of entity
> - Set different order for different set of arguments
> - Create one view that sets the order, and create as many views as you like that shows that order
> - Use core tabledrag.js or jQuery UI draggable javascripts to set the order

Steps to use this module and views to order nodes:

- Download [draggable views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) and views module and enable in your site.
- Create a view to list your nodes say field will be node title and choose Format as Table.
- Add draggable fields as additional field in Fields section. You can use submit as well as ajax submit once you ordered your nodes.
- Add Draggable weight as ascending order in sort criteria.
  [image]
- Save the view and view it in the page.
- My list will be like this:
  [image]

  - Drag and drop the pointer to order the nodes and hit submit.
    [image]

Comment: its not providing drag and drop facility for nodes

Comment: How you are checking this? Have u created a view with draggable views as format?

Comment: on my website i m also looking for the module for odering nodes..but this module is not providing any option fr drop and drag

Comment: I am looking for module which provide drag and drop facilty in UI to reorder your content or nodes

Comment: Okay. To which user, you are going to show your ordered nodes? If you are using custom page to show your ordered nodes, then views with draggable module can be used easily.

Comment: @manikandankannan Thanks for sharing such a good solution with me. Unfortunately it seems difficult to me. Can you please do me a favor by just guiding step wise or complete?

Comment: @SaeedAfzal I edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: @manikandankannan Thanks for modifying this answer. It was really very helping. Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are many modules for this purpose. You can use [Node Order](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeorder) module

> The nodeorder module gives users an easy way to order nodes within
>   their taxonomy terms.
>
> By default, the taxonomy module orders listings of nodes by stickiness
>   and then by node creation date -- most recently posted nodes come
>   first.

Or to choose from the list of modules for this purpose, you can have a look at the [Comparison of Node/Entity Ordering Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/398508) page.

Comment: I did installed this module Node Order. But I cannot see the drag and drop icon on admin/content screen. Can you please help that how I can fix it to reorder of my multiple nodes?

Comment: FYI, the drag & drop feature won't be available in admin/content page. You can order using 'per-vocabulary basis' or by creating a view for that. Kindly go through the documentation for the module at https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeorder

Answer (score 2):

[Nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module was built exactly for the same reason :)

> The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose, such as:
>
> - A block listing teasers for the five top news stories on a site
> - A user’s favorite music albums
> - A group of favorite from which one is randomly displayed
>
> Nodequeue provides a simple drag-and-drop interface to manually order any queue. Additionally, it allows nodes to be added and removed from queues without needing edit permissions to the node. Nodes can be added to queues either from a queue management tab or by links on the node teaser.

Follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3oCr5iWeTc) to create a nodequeue.

Comment: Yes, nodequeue is especially useful if you want to hand-pick a selection of nodes. When you need to order all nodes (or all of a certain node type) Draggable Views makes more sense IMO.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comparison of "node ordering modules" at
https://www.drupal.org/node/398508

Comment: This looks like a link only answer. I suggest you expand your answer by also including a relevant summary of it (or something similar). If you do, leave the link (to where you copied it from) in it also.